# Call functions in a function in prolog

Tags: function, prolog

I'm new to prolog and currently have this situation: I have declared several functions

```
 a(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr mod 19. 
 b(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr mod 4. 
 c(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr mod 7. 
 h1(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr div 100. 
 h2(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr div 400.
```

All this functions work. I now tried this:

```
 n(Jahr, Z) :- Z is h1(Jahr, Y) - h2(Jahr, X).
```

But it gives me an exception

> ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

I tried to google and research this question but, I guess because of my still ongoing learning process, I couldn't find an understandable answer yet, so I just ask here.

Thanks for helping a prolog beginner out!

Comment: I'm sorry if I missused the vocabulary of prolog. I'm visiting a prolog class since 2 weeks. I know that there's still a lot to learn and so I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your rule should look like

```
n(Jahr, Z) :- h1(Jahr, H1), h2(Jahr, H2), Z is H1 - H2.
```

that is introduce a variable for each value needed by your calculation (a simple subtraction, here).

Alternatively, some Prolog (notably SWI-Prolog) offers a way to *extend* the arithmetic sublanguage, via [arithmetic_function](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arithmetic%3aarithmetic_function/1). Then you should declare

```
?- [user].

:- arithmetic_function(h1/1).
:- arithmetic_function(h2/1).

h1(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr div 100. 
h2(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr div 400.
```

after that you can use such functions:

```
?- A = 2013, Z is h1(A) - h2(A).
A = 2013,
Z = 15.
```

note that arithmetic_function is deprecated...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! :) I just tried it and sadly get another exception: 

5 ?- n(800, Z). 
ERROR: n/2: Undefined procedure: (-)/2
Exception: (7) h1(800, _G945)-h2(800, _G948) ? creep

Do you have an idea?

Comment: All my functions from above plus the one you posted: 

 a(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr mod 19. 
 b(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr mod 4. 
 c(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr mod 7. 
 h1(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr div 100. 
 h2(Jahr, Z) :- Z is Jahr div 400. 
 
 n(Jahr, Z) :- h1(Jahr, H1) - h2(Jahr, H2), Z is H1 - H2.

I then tried it with "n(800, Z)." and received that exception from above. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: there a hyphen instead of a comma, correct it taking the code above. I eventually did this mistake, and corrected it immediatly. You must have been more fast than me to grab the code...

Comment: Oh, haha, you are completely right! I was too fast, now everything works as expected. Thank you!